# access the excel file with userform for atlest ten people and the code for this should be written in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

This could be the last trial of mine in trying with the stackoverflow.

The project is under progress.

The aim of the project is to done using automation tool that is macro(VBA)

After assigning the test to all the users, all the users will open their excel files at a time. When they open they must see the userform but not the excel.

I tried the code and it is pasted here.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

   Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
   Dim objFolder As Folder
   Dim objFile As File
   Dim strpath As String
   Dim a As Workbook
   Dim filename As String
    strpath = Range("B1").Value
    Set objFolder = FSO.GetFolder(strpath)
   If objFolder.Files.Count = 0 Then
   MsgBox "No files were found....", vbExclamation
   End If
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    a    = "Good"
       Workbook.Open (a)
      VBA.UserForms.Add(a).Show
      a.Show
   Next objFile
    End Sub
```

Comment: If unable to get the answer please mention it .

Comment: You can format your code in the code editor with the "**{ }**" brackets :)

Comment: Do I understand correctly: you want to use Excel to show a form yet Excel should not be visible?

Comment: Yes.  All the students if they open there excel file they should see the userform that has All the best message and the userform has link to another userform and there they will find the questions to answer